# when I use subl command, it opens a file "usr/local/bin/subl" along with the file or folder I wanted to open

Tags: sublimetext3

when I use subl command, it opens a file "usr/local/bin/subl" along with the file or folder I wanted to open

I want to change the settings to that it does not open this file, and only opens the file or directory I told it to open in sublime.

Answer (score 0):

This currently can't be done with Sublime Text (build 3125).

There is an open ticket on issue tracker: https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/28.